# c# - how to set specific control indentification in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i desire to create ASP.NET control with specific identification with C#:

```
MyControl myControl = new MyControl { ID = "my-control" };
```

but after render, the identification become:

```
<div id="ctl13_my-control"> ... </div>
```

i desire for style sheet of cascade:

```
<div id="my-control"> ... </div>
```

how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property instead:

```
MyControl myControl = new MyControl { ClientID = "my-control" };
```

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET 4 and above, you can set the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) property to determine how the control's ID is rendered. For example using `Static` means whatever ID you give the control is what you will see in the HTML source.

Comment: @DavidTansey Cheers dude, was in the middle of editing my answer by adding a link to that page. Man, you gotta be so quick on this site!

Comment: I could have said the same thing about 30 seconds before you said it -- when YOUR ANSWER popped up.  Ha!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the property "clientidmode" set to "static"

```
<div id="my-control" clientidmode="Static"> ... </div>
```

Been there, done that.